# rear derailleur installation

Tags: derailleur

Today I installed my new rear derailleur and chain. I am not completely satisfied. My questions are..

Is my cable clamp routing correct? I know my cable is frayed, i will use a new one.

Did i install the derailleur correctly? I made sure that the tab was against the hanger that i circled in black

The pulley wheel is super close to the cassette and b scew doesn't do much

I think i routed the chain incorrectly in the picture but i tryed both ways and i thought they both rubbed? I believe the chain may be alittle Too long awell. I need to get a chain breaker

Honestly it shifted okay but im not super impressed. Lastly is there a way to index the gears so there is a light touch(pressure)required while shifting. I was thinking if you set the initial cable pressure as lighly as possible before clamping it will be easier to shift? If that makes any sense.sorry about duplicate photos[[image: derailleur][1]]

[[image: 1hanger][![hanger[![y[![g

1. [![h[image: https://ibb.co/5T92xsC https://ibb.co/pLh0FdT https://ibb.co/bgh3czP https://ibb.co/hYGDZXJe]

][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZjxk.jpg)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZjxk.jpg)][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUGt6.jpg)][7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RKRS.jpg)

[image: 1]

[image: tie]

Comment: The chain is routed correctly through the cage. Must be behind the pin/plate that should prevent it from slipping (behind=towards the rear of the bike). Just check page 26 here: https://si.shimano.com/de/pdfs/dm/GN0001/DM-GN0001-26-GER.pdf

Comment: The derailleur doesn't appear to be on the hanger properly. I can see the Stop of the deralleur's mount is not against the hanger stop. It needs to be reattached with the orientation further clockwise.

Comment: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61rfY326nQL._SL256_.jpg Shows correct orientation.

Comment: I think you are correct. I have the same impression based on the position of the hex-bolts, but you seem to have a better eye and understanding.

Answer (score 2):

What is the exact model of derailleur? Is it compatible with your cassette capacity wise(34T large cog)? Have you inserted the B-screw as far as it goes in the picture? It should at least adjust the derailleur position, if not something is off. Is the derailleur resting correctly on the hanger? Look at page 12, bottom right.

https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/dm/GN0001/DM-GN0001-26-ENG.pdf

The chain is routed correctly in the second picture.

*Lastly is there a way to index the gears so there is a light touch(pressure)required while shifting. I was thinking if you set the initial cable pressure as lighly as possible before clamping it will be easier to shift?*

No, this will only force you to correct the overly loose tension with extra turns on the barrel adjuster when indexing the shifting.

Old dirty wires/housings can have a surprising detrimental effect on the feel of shifting. The shifters themselves can also be the issue.

Comment: Also, it's very hard to tell from the photos, but have you checked to make sure the hanger is aligned properly? A crooked hanger will make adjusting your derailleur very difficult.

Comment: Its a Shimano Deore RD-M592 9 Speed SGS Shadow Rear Derailleur. Can handle 36 teeth. Yes in that picture the b screw is in all the way and doesn't really change anything. I believe i installed it correctly with the tab agaisnt the hanger. I circled it in black. The hanger itself is brand new.